# how to use map to reduce objects creation in spring MVC web app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, optimization, dao

**Situation** : I am designing a spring MVC based web app , i have a table called `customers` it consists of 3 columns `id` , `property` , `property value` .

`id` is not `primary key`.

Following is the `Model` class i am using :

```
public class prop {

private String id;
private String property;
private String property_value;

/*setter and getters of these three variables ...*/
}
```

and my Dao is :

```
@Repository("Dao")
public class Dao implements{

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public List<Model> listProp(String id) {

    final String sql = "select * from customers where id = ? ";
    final List<Model> list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{id}, new Mapper());
    return list;
 }
}
```

And my `Mapper` class is :

```
public class Mapper implements RowMapper<Model> { 

public Model mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Model m = new Model();
    m.setId(rs.getString(1));
    m.setProperty(rs.getString(2));
    m.setValue(rs.getString(3));
    return wl;
}
}
```

**Problem** :Now i have a scenario in which id=1 has 4 properties , so it will have 4 corresponding rows and 4 Model objects are created,

if id=1 has say 100 properties , then 100 `model` objects are created which is inefficient , i want that ,  for all rows with id=1  one `Model`object must be created , i tried using `map` but couldn't implement it properly can somebody please help ?

**Note**: In UI i am displaying all the records as they are present in DB

Comment: I don't quite understand your design. Judging by this query: `select * from customers where id = ? ` how can you have 4 results?

Comment: as i said id is not primary key , so above query will retrieve all records which have a particular id

Answer (score 0):

You can modify class prop as

```
public class prop {
    private String property;
    private String property_value;
/*setter and getters of these three variables ...*/
}
```

Modify Mapper code accordingly  to use HashMap.

```
public class Mapper {

Map<String ,List<Model>> map = new HashMap<String , List<Model>>();

    public Map<String , Model> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Model m = new Model();
        m.setProperty(rs.getString(2));
        m.setValue(rs.getString(3));

        if(map.containsKey(rs.getString(1))) {
            List<Model> modelList = map.get(rs.getString(1));
            modelList.add(m);
        } else {
            List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
            modelList.add(m);
            map.put(rs.getString(1),modelList);
        }

        return map;

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate or explain more ? may be a POC

Comment: Edited my answer above